# Is it possible to connect thermal masses (capacitors) in series?

Tags: capacitance

We can find the equivalent capacitance of two electrical capacitors if they are connected in series or parallel.

And if two thermal masses are connected in parallel the method of finding the capacitance is the same as the method we use for electrical capacitors, i.e., we just sum the capacitance of two capacitors.

So, can we also find the equivalent capacitance for two thermal masses connected in series using the same method we use for electrical capacitors, or is it even possible to connect them in series?

Edit: Thermal mass which is a term also known as thermal capacitor is analog of electrical capacitor, but they appear in thermal circuits.

The similarity between thermal and electrical capacitor can be seen from the ODE's that describe them.

$Q = c \cdot m \frac{dT}{dt}$ describes how the temperature (across variable) of the mass changes, given the energy flow (through variable).

Here $C = c \cdot m$ can be defined as the capacitance of thermal mass (the capacitor).

$I = C \frac{dV}{dt}$ describes the how the voltage (again the across variable) changes, given the current flow (the through variable of an electrical circuit).

Ultimately, my question is we can connect electrical capacitor in both series and parallel, and we can also connect thermal capacitor in parallel, but it's not clear to me if it is physically connect thermal capacitors in series.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the capacitance of thermal masses. Please elaborate

Comment: Thermal masses can be characterized by their thermal resistance, which is somewhat analogous to electrical resistance in circuits, and by their heat capacity, which is **not** analogous in the same manner to the electrical capacitance. For example, connecting two thermal masses in series increases their total heat capacity; this is not the case for the electrical capacitance of two capacitors connected in series. With this in mind, please consider clarifying your question (what do you mean by "capacitance"?), ideally with a diagram of the connection.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thermal masses are characterized by their resistances of course, but they are represented by a thermal resistor in a circuit, the thermal mass in a circuit represents how the energy is stored with time which is described by the same differential equation as an electrical capacitor.

Comment: They obviously aren't the same equation, as heat flux isn't current and temperature isn't voltage. As noted above, you can construct an analogy in which thermal conductivity mediates heat flux from an applied temperature difference, just as electrical conductivity mediates current from an applied voltage. But the analogy breaks down when it comes to capacitance because small thermal energy parcels don't have positive and negative charges (or any such mechanism) that causes them to repel and attract. That would be the debunked theory of [caloric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caloric_theory).

Comment: On paper, I can connect two thermal masses in series and calculate their equivalent capacitance by 1/C_eq = 1/C_1 + 1/C_2, just like two electrical capacitors in series. But does that make sense in the physical world? I guess, you answered it in your previous answer by saying a thermal masses have resistance, so if we disregard the resistance, the thermal mass 1 can't constrict the energy flow for the thermal mass 2, so the C_eq can't be less than C_1 or C_2, and what I understand from this is the thermal masses can't be connected in series.